# 2D colormap in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2d vector `(x,y)` and I need to find a 2D colormap that maps these coordinates to a smooth colormap. The color code will depend only on the `(x,y)` value. For instance,

- white around the center,
- more red as we go to the northeast,
- more blue as we go the southeast,
- more green as we go to the northwest,
- and more green as we go to the southwest.

In other words:

```
green         red
       white
green         blue
```

I didn't find anything in `matplotlib` correspond to my need. I thought about converting the coordinates into magnitude and phase but still the problem be the same. I also thought about adding a dummy dimension to the vector `(x,y)` to make it a 3d dimension and then normalize the resulted 3D vector. Then, feed it to `cmap` parameter in the `matplotlib` plots. However, this would produce a non-smooth colors. Any leads?

A sample of the color map:

[image: sample color map]

Comment: it's very hard to imagine what you are trying to plot from these words.. So the idea is plotting it as a x and y, and the color is dependent on another variable z, which you have to define

Comment: do you have any code or something you have tried? I think it's more useful

Comment: @StupidWolf. The color code will solely depend on the value (x,y). I tried to add a variable z so I can have 3d data which can be mapped to RGB. Here is a good example of my need: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/549dcda5e4b0a47d0ae1db1e/t/556489ffe4b00576f8456dec/1432668688862/?format=1500w. so based on (x,y) you can pick up a color and it's smooth.

Comment: I guess the question is what are you trying to **plot** with this color map.

Comment: @QuangHoang do you mean what the actual data is?

Comment: @randomndrandom Yes, the data you are trying to plot.

Comment: @QuangHoang. It's neural signals from the brain..I ended up with a representation of this signal in two dim and I want to color them smoothly so I can reflect their color on the 3D brain model. This is why I need the 2 dim and need them to be smoothly; so a reader can follow up with the abstract 2-d plot and how they reflected on the brain. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

So to restate the problem to ensure that I understand it correctly: you would like to have two different colormap channels, not a single one?

I don't see a direct way to do this in matplotlib, there are two options:

- plot the same data multiple times with different color channels/colormaps/transparencies
- define your own custom 2D-to-RGB color map and pass an array of RGB triplets to the plotting function

For the "hack-y" multiple plotting solution:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb, rgb_to_hsv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xydata = np.array([(x,y) for x in np.arange(-1.,1.1,0.1) for y in np.arange(-1.,1.1,0.1)], dtype=float)
x_colorfunc = lambda xy: xy.T[0].max() - np.abs(xy.T[0])
y_colorfunc = lambda xy: np.abs(xy.T[1])
y_colormap_coord = y_colorfunc(xydata)
x_colormap_coord = x_colorfunc(xydata)
x_colormap = "plasma"
y_colormap = "Greys"


plt.figure("2d_colormap_hack")
plt.scatter(xydata.T[0], xydata.T[1], c=x_colormap_coord, cmap= x_colormap, alpha=1.0)
plt.scatter(xydata.T[0], xydata.T[1], c=y_colormap_coord, cmap= y_colormap, alpha=0.6)
```

Which produces

[image: 2-channel hack graph]

You can do anything you'd like tor the custom 2D-to-color function, but here are two suggestions:

```
def xy_color_func(xy):
    # using np.divide handles `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide`
    xy_ratio = np.divide(xy.T[1], xy.T[0], out=np.ones_like(xy.T[0]), where=(xy.T[0]!=0) )
    xy_angle_frac = (4/np.pi)*np.abs(np.arctan(xy_ratio))
    xy_mag = np.linalg.norm(xy, axis=-1)
    hsl_hue = 1 - 1./6*xy_angle_frac   # hue goes from red to blue 
    hsl_sat = 1 - xy_mag/xy_mag.max()  # 0 is full color saturation, 1 is equal RGB values
    hsl_luminance = 0.75 - 0.25*(xy_mag/xy_mag.max())  # brighter at the "target" point of (0, 0)
    hsv = hsl_to_hsv(hsl_hue, hsl_sat, hsl_luminance)
    rgb = hsv_to_rgb(hsv)
    return rgb

def hsl_to_hsv(hsl_hue, hsl_sat, hsl_luminance):
    hsv_hue = hsl_hue
    hsv_v = hsl_luminance + hsl_sat*np.minimum(hsl_luminance, 1-hsl_luminance)
    hsv_sat = 2*(1-np.divide(hsl_luminance, hsv_v, out=np.ones_like(hsv_v), where=(hsv_v!=0) ))
    hsv = np.vstack((hsv_hue, hsv_sat, hsv_v)).T
    return hsv

xy_colors = xy_color_func(xydata)
plt.figure("2d_colormap_func")
plt.scatter(xydata.T[0], xydata.T[1], c=xy_colors)
```

Which produces

[image: 2D color function graph]

It looks like your desired color map needs a few more rules to convert the XY regions to the desired colors,and gradient/blending function to transition from one region to another, similar to the trapezoidal blending shown in [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_to_RGB). In your desired map above,

- "green" is `x<=0`,
- "red" is `x >0 & y < 0`,
- "blue" is `x > 0 & y >= 0`, and
- `white` is `1-magnitude(x,y)`,

One way to achieve this might be to make a grid of points with the desired color in a graphics program (like Gimp or Inkscape), tweak the key coordinates and specified color triplets (in RGB, HSL, or HSV) until you are pleased with the appearance, then use `scipy.interpolate.griddata`[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) to interpolate each of the 3 color channels for your XY data, like the following:

```
key_xy_points = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,-1],[-1,1], [-1,-1]],dtype=float)
key_xy_RGBs = np.array([[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0]],dtype=float)

from scipy.interpolate import griddata

reds = griddata(key_xy_points, key_xy_RGBs.T[0], xydata)
greens = griddata(key_xy_points, key_xy_RGBs.T[1], xydata)
blues = griddata(key_xy_points, key_xy_RGBs.T[2], xydata)

xy_colors_griddata = np.vstack((reds, greens, blues)).T
plt.figure("2d_colormap_griddata")
plt.scatter(xydata.T[0], xydata.T[1], c=xy_colors_griddata)
```

Which produces

[image: 2D color function graph from griddata]

Note: As long as I was writing my own colorspace conversion function, I could have converted directly from HSL to RGB [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), but perhaps one of the commenters can explain why matplotlib.colors has `hsv_to_rgb` but not an `hsl_to_rgb` (running matplotlib v.3.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a color space like hsl or hsv and fix the lightness value (l or v) and use x as h and y as s to represent all the colors. You will need to normalize the values of x and y to make them compatible with the color space components.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to format your colormap as a 3D array with RGB values i.e. an array `cmap` of shape (256,256,3).
You fill this array with color values to make up the colormap.
You then adjust your two variables `(x,y)` to the range 0→255 and convert them to dtype = int, `(x_int, y_int)`.

You then sample your `cmap` based on `(x_int, y_int)`

```
image = cmap[y_int,x_int]
```

You can then visualize both the colormap and image:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
axes[0].imshow(image)
axes[0].imshow(cmap)
```

if you do not wish to do this manually you can check out the package at https://colorstamps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (pip install colorstamps)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import colorstamps
# img = (100,200,2) example data
img = colorstamps.helpers.get_random_data()
# map data to colormap
rgb, stamp = colorstamps.apply_stamp(img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1], 'peak',
                                   vmin_0 = -1.2, vmax_0 = 1.2,
                                   vmin_1 = -1, vmax_1 = 1,
                                 )
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,3), dpi = 100)
axes[0].imshow(rgb)
# show colormap as overlay
overlaid_ax = stamp.overlay_ax(axes[0],
                lower_left_corner = [0.7,0.85], width = 0.2)
overlaid_ax.set_ylabel(r'$\phi$')
overlaid_ax.set_xlabel(r'$\omega$')
# also show colormap as in separate ax to illustrate functionality
stamp.show_in_ax(axes[1])
axes[1].set_ylabel(r'$\phi$')
axes[1].set_xlabel(r'$\omega$')
```

[image]

This is a package I built because I had the same requirements as the question asker.