# How to generate a color map like taht in this paper?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

Thus, the colormap should be in 2D which consists of 2 axes: confidence value; and flow field horizontally.

I went through the visualization code of some optical flow projects(since they also need to convert (u,v) into (R, G, B)), but such code doesn't satisfy the color in this paper.
How can I generate a custom colorwheel?

Comment: This has been asked before: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61965021/8881141) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630020/8881141) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41967868/8881141).